# A way to find what a Java object was initialized as instead of declared type?

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

I don't know if I'm missing something here, but I am having trouble casting an object to its actual, initialized type. Basically, if I create an object with "SuperClass sc = new SubClass()," then I call a method on sc, I want the method to be able to call method(Subclass) instead of method(Superclass). Example shown below:

```
public class Example
{
    public static void act(SuperClass a) {
        System.out.println("SuperClass");
    }

    public static void act(SubClass a) {
        System.out.println("SubClass");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass sc = new SubClass();

        // want to find a way to call act(SubClass) instead of act(SuperClass)
        act(sc);
   }
}

class SuperClass {}
class SubClass extends SuperClass {}
```

I am using the visitor pattern right now, but I'm wondering if there are other ways to do this, maybe via the Java Reflection API?

Thanks alot in advance!

== edit ==

I know that generally with OO it's better to stick the functionality back to the superclass/subclasses themselves, but for my specific use cases I have a bunch of subclasses that are immutable model classes, which should be passed to different kinds of execution engines (think different "Example" classes). The subclasses/model classes should only hold immutable information, nothing more, and the actual real functionality lies with the execution engine (Example class). That's why I am wondering about alternatives to the visitor's pattern. Does anyone have a way to recover the actual "initialized" information in Java? If so, thank you so much.

And because of the nature of the problem, I can't use direct casting...
Imagine if I have an arraylist of SuperClass, where each element may be SubClass1, SubClass2, SubClass3, all extending from SuperClass.

Now, when you pull things out of the Arraylist, you get a SuperClass object, even though they may really be SubClass1, SubClass2, SubClass3, etc.

Next, I want to call act(SubClass1), and be able to invoke the correct act() method on the current type. So I want to end up calling act(SubClass1), act(SubClass2), act(SubClass3), instead of act(SuperClass).

== edit again ==

I've came up with a way of doing this via the Java Reflection API, by finding the actual underlying type of the SubClass using Class.forName(classname), then dynamically invoking the method with the correct method signature. I have written this up in answer form somewhere down this page for those who are interested about this problem. Note that this isn't a very efficient way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do here, and you're probably better off with visitor pattern or if-else statements if you're stuck with my situation.

---

So the answer that Nicola Musatti gave is the closest to answering my question, though as he has also pointed out, as the number of SubClasses grow the if-else statements list gets very long. I will choose his answer as the accept answer since I hadn't stated clearly in my question that I was hoping to avoid the if-else checks.

Anyways, so I've played around a bit with the Java Reflection API today and came up with this:

```
SuperClass sc = new SubClass();

// Get the actual class of sc. actualClass now is SubClass.
Class actualClass = Class.forName(sc.getClass().getCanonicalName());

// Basically invoking act(SubClass sc) instead of act(SuperClass sc)
Class parameters[] = {actualClass};
Method method = Example.class.getMethod("act", parameters);
Object arguments[] = {sc};
method.invoke(null, arguments);
```

This is surely not a great way to do things, especially because of the performance penalty impose by the Java Reflection API. This might be better than visitor pattern or the if-else checks if you have a million subclasses, since it's probably less code to manage, however I'll stick with the visitor pattern for now since I don't have a million subclasses to manage.

Regardless, just thought I would post this here to show that it can be done, just for those who are curious.

Comment: you are perverting OO.  It's kinda one of the main point of OO: you pass a message and the object itselfs knows how to respond to that message.  Here you're creating an *Example* which knows way too much about implementation details and which tries to take responsibility for an action that should be executed by the object.  I'm pretty sure you're way off base in what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The classes i have (a bunch of Subclasses) are supposed to be immutable model classes that are passed to and used by different engines. They are supposed to be holding information, nothing more, and thus why I am not willing to put any other functionality in it. Basically, I am supposed to have many different "Example" (engines) that act on different, related "SubClass" (model classes).

Comment: Immutability doesn't mean there can't be accessor methods. What you would have to put in won't be 'functionality' just a polymorphic means of accessing the data within.

Comment: As I said, I have many different example engines, I don't want to add a method for each execution engine in my model classes. It doesn't really make sense either, since the model classes are just... model classes. The execution engine is supposed to be the one doing the work. Why clutter my model classes with all these extra method, and having to make changes to them whenever I make new engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is the Visitor pattern. If you have a specific situation where you know the actual type of sc you can indeed use a cast, as was already suggested, possibly preceded by a type check as in

```
if ( sc instanceof SubClass ) act((SubClass)sc);
```

However the Visitor pattern was invented because this approach doesn't scale up when the number of classes you need to handle grows.

Last but not least, sometimes the simplest approach is just to keep around a variable of the actual type:

```
SubClass scc = new SubClass();
SuperClass sc = scc;
act(scc);
```

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't you define `act()` in `SuperClass` and `SubClass`? That way the correct method will be called regardless of the type of the reference to the object.

Edit: If I remember correctly the visitor pattern defines something like an `accept()` method on the elements to be visited which allows the visitor to polymorphically access whatever it's interested in in the visited elements.

Comment: yes, my subclasses do have the accept() method. just left them out of the example for brevity

Comment: So whatever the visitor needs to do it should accomplish that through the `accept()` method.

Comment: yes, i'm saying that i want to know of alternatives to the visitor pattern, meaning, removing those accept() methods and being able to directly call act(SubClass). I was wondering if there are things in the Java Reflection API that would do that. I've been looking at Class.cast(), but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Seems like you're heading for trouble - trying to basically implement polymorphism using something else than polymorphism. If it's a one-shot app you can use Reflection, cast, whatever, but I would advise against it in something that is meant to be reused.

Comment: Well even if it is out of curiosity to see if it can be done, are there any ways to do so?

Comment: In that case check the answer by Nicola Musatti

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
act((SubClass)sc);
```

??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make the method `act` member of the SupperClass class, and then override it in SubClass class.

Comment: All methods are virtual in Java

Comment: I am struggling with my C++ background. Thanks!